# Reset AirTag without iPhone

Tags: find-my, airtag

I recently got an Android phone and forgot to remove my AirTags from findmy before giving the iPhone away. I still have my MacBook. But the findmy app won't let me reset my AirTags as in remove them from my Apple ID.

Answer (score 1):

You need an iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch to remove Find My network items from your Apple ID.

> AirTag and Find My network accessories can be removed from an Apple ID only on iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch.

[Apple Support - If an item or device is connected to another Apple ID](https://support.apple.com/en-us/102620)

Comment: And you cannot reset them from say my girlfriend's iPhone?

Comment: @H3R3T1K You would have to sign out of Apple ID from her account, then sign in with yours which would be disruptive. Easiest thing to do if you're not to far from an Apple Store is to go to one and tell them your situation and ask for a device to sign into and remove them from the account.